# SQL ORACLE MERGE Table

Tags: oracle, merge

I want to update my table `MA_PARTICIPANT` using `MERGE UPDATE CLAUSE`. I want to update two columns:

`MA_PARTICIPANT.CUSTOMER_RK,MA_PARTICIPANT.DEACT_FLG. CUSTOMER_RK` will be updated with my second table `TABLE_CHANGE` which consists two columns:-

`CUSTOMER_RK,NEW_CUSTOMER_RK. MA_PARTICIPANT.DEACT_FLG` in table `MA_PARTICIPANT` may be 'Y' or 'N' and if it 'N' then i should change it to 'Y',but if it already 'Y' then i should not update this column. Merging tables will be on `MA_PARTICIPANT.part_id = TABLE_CHANGE.part_id`, but i dont know how to use merge with condition on `MA_PARTICIPANT.DEACT_FLG`.

Finally, each CUSTOMER_RK which i update should has flg = 'Y'

simple example of MA_PARTICIPANT:

```
PART_ID  CUSTOMER_RK  DEACT_FLG   
1          10          Y   
2          10          N   
3          20          Y
```

simple example of TABLE_TO_CHANGE:

```
PART_ID CUSTOMER_RK NEW_CUSTOMER_RK
1         10          100
2         10          100
3         20          200
```

MA_PARTICIPANT after update:

```
PART_ID  CUSTOMER_RK  DEACT_FLG   
1          100          Y   
2          100          Y   
3          200          Y
```

I suppose that that it will be:

```
merge INTO MA_PARTICIPANT P USING 
  (SELECT * from TABLE_TO_CHANGE) TT ON (TT.PART_ID = P.PART_ID)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE    
  SET 
  IF P.DEACTIVATED_FLG <> 'Y' THEN
    P.CUSTOMER_RK = TT.NEW_CUSTOMER_RK,
    P.DEACTIVATED_FLG = 'Y'
  ELSE 
     P.CUSTOMER_RK = TT.NEW_CUSTOMER_RK
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a where clause in your update part of the merge statement. If I was you, I'd write the MERGE statement first and add it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should update all matching rows, setting `DEACT_FLG` to Y and `CUSTOMER_RK` to `NEW_CUSTOMER_RK`:

```
MERGE INTO MA_PARTICIPANT P
USING TABLE_TO_CHANGE TT 
ON (TT.PART_ID = P.PART_ID)
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE    
  SET CUSTOMER_RK = NEW_CUSTOMER_RK,
      DEACT_FLG =   'Y'
```

Comment: I should update EACH value CUSTOMER_RK that i have in table TABLE_TO_CHANGE and values DEACTIVATED_FLG depending on the value in table MA_PARTICIPANT - if value 'N' then i udpate it for 'Y' else - not update. Finally, each CUSTOMER_RK which i update should has flg = 'Y'

Comment: If so, we have no need for `IF`, `DECODE`, ...; in `MERGE`, for every matching row, we can update `CUSTOMER_RK = NEW_CUSTOMER_RK` and `DEACT_FLG = 'Y'`